# Deriving intertemporal budget constraint

Tags: macroeconomics

Suppose I have the period budget constraints, where $c$ is consumption
and $k$ is capital:
$$
c_{0}+k_{1}=Rk_{0}
$$
$$
c_{1}+k_{2}=Rk_{1}
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
$$
c_{T}+k_{T+1}=Rk_{T}
$$
and
$$
k_{T+1}=0
$$
The notes say that with repeated substitution, the consolidated intertemporal
budget constraint should be:
$$
c_{1}+\frac{1}{R}c_{1}+\frac{1}{R^{2}}c_{2}+...+\frac{1}{R^{T}}c_{T}=Rk_{0}
$$
I am at a loss at how to get this. I tried substituting:
$$
k_{1}=Rk_{0}-c_{0}
$$
and
$$
k_{2}=Rk_{1}-c_{1}=R^{2}k_{0}-Rc_{1}-c_{1}
$$
and so on, but this just seems to get messier. I think the terminal
condition, i.e.
$$
c_{T}=Rk_{T}
$$
is probably useful here, but I am not sure how to work backwards
with it. Any help on this is much appreciated!

Comment: Try $k_1=\frac{c_1}{R}+\frac{k_2}{R}$

Answer (score 1):

I actually tried the following:
$$
c_{0}+k_{1}=Rk_{0}\implies k_{1}=Rk_{0}-c_{0}
$$
$$
k_{2}=R^{2}k_{0}-Rc_{0}-c_{1}
$$
and so on. This gives us:
$$
c_{T}+R^{T}c_{0}+R^{T-1}c_{1}+...+Rc_{T-1}=R^{T+1}k_{0}
$$
Multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{R^{T}}$
$$
c_{0}+\frac{c_{1}}{R}+....+\frac{c_{T}}{R^{T}}=Rk_{0}
$$